# Open C#/XAML view from a WinJS app

Tags: c#, xaml, winjs, win-universal-app

I am currently trying to open a XAML view from a C# class in a Windows 10 UAP WinJS project.
To do that, I have a C# class I instantiate from javascript then I call a method on it to load the XAML view.
However, when I call CoreApplication.CreateNewView(), it triggers an exception with the message "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong (I'm not used to Windows 10 Apps), or if it is simply not possible to Open XAML/C# view in a WinJS app.

Here is the JS code I use to call my C# code:

```
var csClass1 = new CsCode.Class1();
csClass1.loadXamlPage();
```

Here is the C# code which throws an exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace CsCode
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        public async void loadXamlPage()
        {
            //throw "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage1), null);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stuck in the same situaion. Let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot open a c#/XAML control from a WinJS app